# Nest Camera - WebRTC - How can I set video quality params?

Tags: camera, webrtc, video-streaming, nest, frame-rate

I'm trying to configure a Nest video stream (from a doorbell in this case), but we need to reduce the quality of the video due to resource limitations on the client device. Is there any way to reduce the frame rate, resolution, video quality, bitrate, etc on the WebRTC camera stream?

Tried to set the following params on the SDP Offer, but none seem to be honored by the camera: framerate, maxheight, maxwidth, etc.

Example in the SDP Offer:

```
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 122 102 121 127 120 125 107 108 109 35 36 124 119 123 118 114 115 116 37
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:6ReD
    ...
    a=framerate:8
    ...
    a=maxheight:490
```